# Suppose that $f (x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$. Prove that $\lim x f (x) = 0$ as $x→0$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

(a) Suppose that $f (x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$. Prove that $\lim xf(x) = 0$ as $x→0$.

(b) Prove that the converse of (a) is not true. That is, find a function $f(x)$ such that $\lim xf(x) = 0$ as $x→0$, but $f$ is not continuous at $x = 0$.

It's obvious that any large number multiplied by $0$ is $0$ but how would I go about proving this? I don't understand.

Comment: (b) Let $f(x)=1$ if $x=0$, and let $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For part (a), since $f$ is continuous at 0, $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0)$.  Now $\lim_{x \to 0} x f(x) = ?$ (does the limit of a product equal the product of the limits?)

For part (b), think about the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: How would I set a proof knowing that as x approaches 0 since f(x) is continuous at 0, it equals f(0)?

Comment: That is the definition of continuity.  That is, a function $f$ is *defined* to be continuous at a point $c$ if $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$.